# AVD asked me to download system image even though it has been downloaded already

Tags: android, android-emulator, avd-manager

[image]

You can see I've already downloaded and installed the system image yet AVD kept asking me to download it again.

[image]

How do I fix this and if not how do I manually create devices without using AVD manager? THX.

Comment: "You can see I've already downloaded and installed the system image" -- that is not what the `system-images/` directory should look like. It should contain a list of platforms (e.g., `android-28` for API Level 28). Drilling down into there will eventually yield an `x86_64` directory.

Comment: Fixed! Thank you very much!